# how to change src folder name for the project generated by angular client?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to change the default src folder name created by angular client, but it throws great many errors if I do it.

Is it possible to change the default folder names generated by ng new `<app-name>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

angluar client uses webpack and its configuration can be controlled using the below command. run it from your project folder created by angular client.

ng eject;

the above command will result in webpack.config.js; it will have references to src folder, update all occurrences in the file with the name you choose to rename src.

Note: 
once you perform ng eject; the default commands like ng build are not expected to function; you need to depend on npm as directed at the end of ng eject command execution.

-Vikas.